# Getting leading zero displayed without quotes

Tags: excel, coldfusion, leading-zero, cfspreadsheet

I want to remove single but when I remove it, then leading zero is not displayed.

**I want leading zero to be displayed but without quotes.**

My column data type is varchar :

```
<cfquery name="getStudent" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
        SELECT CONCAT('\'',U.user_gov_id) as User_gov_id  , 
        U.user_first_name , U.user_last_name , CONCAT('\'', U.user_mobile ) as Mobile_Number  
        , U.user_address, U.user_street_number, U.user_city , U.user_post_code , 
        DATE_FORMAT(U.delivery_date, '%Y-%M-%d %h:%i:%s')  
        FROM tblUSER U INNER JOIN tblUSER_PAYMENT P ON U.user_id = P.user_id 
        WHERE P.other_amount = '250' AND U.isdelivered = 0 AND U.matrix_node_number > 155
    </cfquery>
```

For Excel generation

```
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#fileName1#.xlsx" query="getStudent" overwrite="true" >
  <cfheader   name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#fileName1#.xlsx">
   <cfcontent  type="application/csv" file="#ExpandPath('#fileName1#.xlsx')#" deletefile="yes">
```

Comment: (Edit) CFSpreadsheet only provides basic output, without much in the way of customization. You will need to use SpreadSheet functions instead. If you do a search, there are a few threads on preserving leading zeroes.  In short, you need to format the columns as "text" first, then add the values with functions. I cannot find the specific thread I was thinking of, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772326/querynew-data-types-in-cf9/25789366#25789366) shows how to format a cell as text.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834337/sql-to-excel-loses-trailing-zeros) is about *trailing* zeros, but it is the same general concept, ie format the cells and add data.

Comment: I made a function for that which enforce excel to store as text . and it is working now

Comment: If you think it would be helpful to others, please post your final code as an "answer". (Answering your own question is allowed on S.O.). Otherwise, you can either delete this question or have it closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Format the column as text before writing out the spreadsheet.  In the following example, columns 2 and 3 are formatted as text.

```
<cfscript>
    format={};

    format.date={};
    format.date.dataformat="mm/dd/yyyy";

    format.text={};
    format.text.dataformat="@";

    var theSheet=SpreadSheetNew("OutputSheet");
    SpreadsheetAddRow(theSheet,ArrayToList(query.getColumnNames()));
    SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,query);
    SpreadsheetFormatColumn(theSheet,format.text,2);
    SpreadsheetFormatColumn(theSheet,format.text,3);
    SpreadsheetFormatColumn(theSheet,format.date,6);
</cfscript>


<cfspreadsheet  action="write"
                filename="#ExpandPath(filename)#"
                name="theSheet"
                sheet="1"
                sheetName="Sheet 1"
                overwrite="true">
```